# Postgresql Monitoring using Grafana

Tags: postgresql, datasource, grafana

I am very new in Grafana. We have setup grafana and now we want to monitor our postgresql DB using it.

We have created the postgresql datasource and provide all the required detail of our psql DB machine and connection showing `ok` in Grafana. Now we have imported the Grafana dashboard with id `9948` Dashboard is imported but didn't showing any stats over it.

We are getting the below error:

```
Error pq: relation "collectd" does not exist
Error Templating init failed
pq: relation "identifiers" does not exist
```

We have installed the `collectd` also using `apt install collectd` on DB machine but didn't find any configurable option in `collectd.conf` file.

Can you please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use [pgwatch2](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pgwatch2).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Thank you for your response. We are aware about it. But we need to monitor some other things also like system, application etc. So we want to use Grafana for all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the timescaleDB and create the PG extension.

\c database

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;

Once done, follow the instructions from following git project.

https://github.com/petercelentanojr/timescaledb_collectd_resources/blob/master/collectd_timescaledb_schema/collectd_timescaledb_bootstrap.sql